# How to show up product accessories image in drupal commerce cart?

Tags: drupal, commerce

I have configured drupal commerce module properly.
Now I have to display product image and product accessories image on cart.

I have solved it but product image and product accessories image are displayed in separate table td data.

Please tell me any solution ASAP.

Comment: there is a view which is responsible to the cart table, just add desired fields.

Comment: i know there is view but view has different field for product image and product-accessories image actually i want only one table header if there are product accessories then it displayed or product image in table data..thanks for reply

Comment: DrupalCommerce is very flexible and customizable, I don't have time to test it but I am sure that you can add those fields (if there is no such fields then you can add relationships) and configure table in output (such as `hide column if empty` and so on..). And also you can alter view ouput with `hook_views_query_alter` hook